# Submit a review(data) through android app on a url

Tags: java, android, dom, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to add a functionality in my app which submits a review of a place on the place's google plus account ..

As you might be knowing the format of the google plus page ..
It has a button "Write a review" (Which is not a button but a clickable 'div')
On pressing this button , a dialogue appears which has a field to write review , It is here i want to actually write the review through the code and press the submit button .

Please help me through this ..
How to achieve this thing  ??

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup parses HTML.  It does not execute JavaScript or emulate a browser, so there's no dialog box for it to interact with.

You could try using a browser's network monitor feature (part of their developer tools) to see what requests are made when the dialog box is submitted, then simulate those requests from your application.  You could also see if there's a Google+ API for submitting reviews other than from the place's Google+ page.  APIs are easier to use, robust against changes in the web page's HTML, and don't risk violating terms of service that prohibit automation.  Finally, you could try a browser automation tool (commonly used for unit testing web pages); I don't know of any for Android but I'd be surprised if there aren't any.